# Realtime pith shift (re-sample) plugin (without correcting/preserving time)

Tags: realtime, pitch

Hi!

Does somebody know, are there any realtime plugins that can control pitch shift without any time correction? I mean “real” pitch shift when you resample audio or like pitch shifting in analog tapes.

For example there is such a thing in Kontakt (“tune” parameter) and it is a great effect especially when you use Kontakt as plugin in your DAW. But I think using Kontakt only for aforementioned purpose a little bit wastefully.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about a sampler. Anything else (an effect plugin) will eventually require an infinite amount of memory as you fill up its buffers faster than you can empty them. Then there's the problem with knowing when to start playing slowly.

Look for the varispeed elastic track modes on your DAW.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried that?
http://www.littleendian.com/overview/

Comment: Hi Jean-Edouard. Nice to see you onboard at SSD!

Comment: Thanks for supporting [SpectrumWorx](https://www.littleendian.com/consumers/spectrumworx).

Answer (score 2):

http://serato.com/pitchntime-pro

^^^^^^This will do exactly what your looking for, I literally use this plugin everyday. Its really easy to use and you'll get the results you want instantly. I highly recommend pitch n time pro.

Comment: its great for drawing pitch curves on waveforms too!

Comment: Side note, worlds fastest Indian is in my top 5 favorite movies list. Great sound track. /end thread jack

Answer (score 0):

I would not make a new topic for this, so i'm aski here:

could you recommend a good sampler for pro tools, where i can pitch down and up the sample maybe more than 1 sent WITHOUT time correction? The iZotope Iris would be the best, but i can't ride the pitch with a knob just with lfo.